# Can I use GitHub to host a self-updating ClickOnce app?

Tags: wpf, github, installation, clickonce

I've got an OSS WPF [application](http://github.com/nesteruk/callsharp) and I want to ship a self-updating installer for it. I know that GitHub has this `raw.github.com` which serves just files so my question is, if I make a directory with a ClickOnce installer, will the ClickOnce self-update mechanism be able to pull updated files from GitHub?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to offer a ClickOnce installer on Github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512029/is-it-possible-to-offer-a-clickonce-installer-on-github)